# modal is sending null value from textbox on button click in php

Tags: php, bootstrap-modal, crud

when I click on button in modal then textbox values becomes null or text disappear.  how to maintain the text in textbox.

```
 Modal :

<div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-  
   dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                 <h4 class="modal-title">Update Country</h4>
            </div>
            <form action="" method="post">
                <div class="modal-body">
                     <input type="text" id="cn" name="pcountry">
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                     <input type="text" id="cph" name="pphone">
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default"       
            name="updatecountry">

                </div>
            </form>

       </div>
```

Jquery Code :

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".btn").click(function(){     
    var cphone =$(this).data('cphone');   
    var cname =  $(this).data('cname');
    $("#cph").val(cphone);
      $("#cn").val(cname);
      </script>
```

[image]

Comment: you can get value of `$phone1` & `$country1`

Comment: yes , but $phone1 and $country1 is not getting values of textbox from modal. always getting null values.

Comment: your code is perfect no need to change so might be some other issue effect on this

Comment: where's the form tag?

Comment: @LecheDeCrema in side modal.

Comment: what's your mysqli database style? procedural?

Comment: Yes. It's not object oriented

Comment: @ImBS : my php code is working fine, problem is in jquery code. on click value of textbox disappear

Comment: @LecheDeCrema my php code is working fine, problem is in jquery code. on click value of textbox disappear

Comment: @kapildevsharma you can check the edit for another way to get the values of your inputs. See if this works. If no then there is a misunderstanding and probably I will need more of your code to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Ofcourse the text in your textboxes will disapear when you are putting null value. I'm reading your code and it is totaly not making sense to me. Now I will explain what is your code doing and hope you will understand your mistakes.

1. `$(this)` in your code is refering to the clicked button.
2. read what jquery's data method doing [here](https://api.jquery.com/data/) and the way you are using it will try to get attribute `data-cphone` and `data-cname` values from the clicked button and since there are no such attributes `var cphone` and `var cname` are both null.

Example:

```
// HTML
<input type="submit" id="my-button" data-cphone="some value" data-cname="some other value">

// JavaScript
// now you will have "some value" inside cphone and "some other value" inside cname 
var cphone =$('#my-button').data('cphone');   
var cname =  $('#my-button').data('cname');
```

3. and finally with this code `$("#cph").val(cphone);` you are setting the value of your `<input>` to **null**

so

> when I click on button in modal then textbox values becomes null or
>   text disappear. how to maintain the text in textbox.

yes my friend this is the expected behaviour.

If you use your code like this:

```
// now your variables will hold the values of those two inputs
var cphone = $("#cph").val();   
var cname = $("#cn").val();

// now for example you can send your values to PHP with AJAX
$.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'path/to/data/processing/script.php',
    data: {name: cname, phone: cphone },
    success: function(response){
       // process your response here
    },
    error: function(err){
       // handle your error here
    },
    complete: function(){
       // clear input values for example 
       $("#cph").val('');   
       $("#cn").val('');
    }
});
```

it will work. Good Luck!

**EDIT**

Check this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cogvdw62/3/) for another way to get the values of the inputs using the jquery's [closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) method to find the parent form and then using the [find](https://api.jquery.com/find/) method to get those two inputs

Comment: when I use ID at the place of this , then it shows same data for all rows.

Comment: Well this might happen if you have this `id` on all the rows. `id` attribute should be used only on a single `HTML` node. Okay then we will use another selector. I will make an edit using another selector